# Should I use Logical Volume Management and Encrypt the installation on SSD?

Tags: installation, 12.10, encryption, ssd, lvm

Should I enable Logical Volume Management on my SSD? What i want to know is if enabling either encrypt the "encrypt the new ubuntu installation for security" option or the "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation" will increase the rate of degradation of my SSD. This is with Ubuntu 12.10 and the SSD is the main drive with two standard hard drives for large data files.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not wear out the drive any sooner.